# Creating an Offline Search Engine for html

Tags: html, search-engine, offline

I am creating a Knowledge Base web for my company on a non-internet connected network. I am not a web developer at all so I am using basic css/html code to build the web pages. I have created the necessary pages, Home, Software Issues, Network Issues, and Create Page.

The create page has a form in which anyone of our SysAdmins can deposit a problem/solution and submit it to the Knowledge Base.

I am looking for some kind of code that would allow me to place a search engine on the web pages so a SysAdmin can type in a problem and search within our Knowledge Base to locate the issue (in the event it has happened before and submitted).

This Knowledge Base also offers additional help such as how-to pages. EX: How to create an account in Windows.

The search engine would search through all pages in the Knowledge Base directory for keywords. Seems simple to me. Is this possible?

Comment: How are they able to submit tickets? Is the system running on a local web server? You might be able to hack something together with JavaScript and DOM searching, but you're going to struggle without using server-side code somewhere along the way. Why not just install XAMPP or WAMP on the network, and you can use PHP or ASP.

Comment: All my users work in 1 room, so speaking across the room is ok for "submitting tickets". No web server. No external software install allowed. Have to make do with what systems I have, Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Try [FullProof](https://reyesr.github.io/fullproof/) *a javascript search engine library for the browser*

From their [website](https://reyesr.github.io/fullproof/):

> **Fullproof** is a javascript library that provides high-quality full-text search in the browser.
>
> This specially makes sense if your webapp is designed to work offline, using the HTML5 offline feature or because your application runs on a possibly disconnected mobile device.

#### Features:

- Boolean and Scoring search engines available, depending on the kind of search your application needs
- Automatic HTML5 storage detection, and graceful degradation, with a configurable constraint-based capabilities system. Currently manages WebSQL, IndexedDB and Memory data storage.
- Full unicode support and normalization, diacritical marks removal, stemming and phonetical algorithms (currently available for english and french)
  Configurable and very easely extensible parsing and token normalization system
- Easy to integrate, zero external dependency, ~100k minified

#### Screenshot

[image]
<sub>(source: [github.com](http://reyesr.github.com/fullproof/img/sc-colors.png))</sub>

#### Note

This gives you all you want, but you need to keep updating the DB each time you put content in your KB.

Comment: To make the issue harder for you...All I can tell you is that my work area is, lets say, restricted. No internet access, no software install allowed, no web-server (obviously), so I have to make do with what I have. I can not bring in outside hardware/software.

Comment: Everyone has a plethora of knowledge stored on text files and brains and are not documenting troubleshooting procedures. I am trying to put all this knowledge on a "Knowledge Base" so in the event Bob comes across a problem that Joe has experienced and Joe is out of the day, Bob can access the KB where Joe has stored the knowledge for future-sake.

Comment: As you said, nothing is needed for this. Get it from somewhere, do it. :)